# node.js cluster: have each worker render different page

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

So I'm using `cluster` to run some chat bots for some friends. And I use `express` to run a single page for each bot. However, cluster doesn't like that. My code (abridged) is something akin to the following:

```
var configs = {
  bot1:"bot1",
  bot2:"bot2"
};

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (var bot in configs) {
    cluster.fork( { file:configs[bot] } );
  }
} else {
  var file = process.env["file"];
  var page = "/" + process.env["file"];
  var express = require("express");
  var web = express();
  web.listen(3000);

  web.get(page,function(req,res){
    res.send( file );
  });
}
```

And while this works good in theory, I'm only getting one bot with an output.

If I go to `example.com:3000/bot2` I get `bot2` as an output.

If I go to `example.com:3000/bot1`, I get `Cannot GET /bot1`.

It seems random which one will work, but never both of them.

Apologies if it's something stupid simple, or if it can't be done. I just find `cluster` more effective at rebooting itself on exits and generally more stable than `child_process`. (sometimes, when I use `child_process`, I'll end up with multiple instances of the same bot, which is tacky.)

Comment: might be a stuppid question but - how many clusters your hardware is having ? means what is output of - `require('os').cpus().length`  ?

Comment: 4, apparently, but this isn't meant for cpu load. Someone told me that using `child_process` to fork each of my bots was stupid, and that I should use `cluster` to fork each of them as it would be better for what I was using it for. I'm fairly certain what I'm asking is impossible, but on the off chance it's not, I'd really like to switch from `child_process` to cluster, as it's miles more stable for me.

Comment: This is all hosted on a vps with 4 cores allotted to me. And I'm not running 2 bots, I'm actually running 14. So I'm unsure what you'd like me to do. I don't want to run every bot on each core, because that wouldn't solve my problem anyway.

Comment: okay, actually I am trying to understand your need, can you try `cluster.on('fork',function(){})` to check how many workers are formed ?

Comment: I have no problem with the workers being spawned. I have a problem with them rendering each individual page. Each worker will render a new web page, but I'm only getting one web page. The chatbots (what I'm forking) work fine, but the web pages simply aren't rendering.

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(page)` just above `web.get(page,function(req,res){` to check if the page is changing correctly?

Comment: Try `(function(bot){ cluster.fork( { file:configs[bot] } ); })(bot);`

Comment: Perhaps the value of bot is pointing at a later entry by the time the fork happens.

Comment: @diosney the logs put the pages correctly, and levi, the bots load fine as is. There are actually about 6 or 7 items I'm storing in the environment object, and all of them get transferred successfully.

Comment: Hey @DaltonGore did you find a better solution to this? I have a very similar scenario, with bot instances running as separate worker processes but wanting a central express API server to route commands and requests to each bot. Was hoping I could have specific routes go to specific bots.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have misunderstood how `cluster` works. It will not help for a situation like this and is primarily designed as a way to start multiple processes listening to the same port for HTTP connections.

What you now have is:

- P1 => Master process which starts P2 and P3.
- P2 => Listening on port 3000 handling `/bot1`
- P3 => Listening on port 3000 handling `/bot2`

When a request comes in on port `3000`, Node has no idea what the URL would be. It just knows that both `P2` and `P3` are set up to handle requests on that port, so it will randomly choose one to handle the request.

If you send a request to /bot1 and Node randomly assigns it to be handled by `P3`, then you will get the error you were seeing `Cannot GET /bot1`, because `P3` has no idea what that path means. The same is true the other way around.

Perhaps what you really want is some number of bot processes and a single process that listens on port 3000 and then forwards the messages to the bot processes using `worker.send()` and such.

Comment: I actually tried this. I stored all the workers in an object and then had the master listen on the ports and send the workers messages when it gets a request (this is how I'm doing it with child process), and it *does* accept all the pages, but it's `/bot1`, `/bot2`, `/bot3` will all show the `bot1` page. So I'm not sure if using worker send is actually differentiating the proper worker.

Comment: @DaltonGore Without seeing your code it is hard to say, but that should work.